# Installing only specific parts of packages (such as scipy) with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, scipy, executable, cx-freeze, python-packaging

I'm making an executable from a Python program which only uses `scipy.integrate`, using cx_Freeze. Now, all of scipy is included, which is over 100 MB. Is there a way to only include the required subpackages?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I struggle with the same thing..

Comment: @deltavisions Unfortunately not, no.